# Can you add a hyperlink inside of a <pre></pre>?

Tags: html, hyperlink, pre

Here's the code I'm working with more or less.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<header></header>
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <pre>
            Text <A herf="linkurl.com">Link</A> Text
        </pre>
    </section>
</div>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get the URL Hyperlink to work inside of the `<pre></pre>`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the fact that you spelled `href` as `herf`.

Comment: Dyslexia must have kicked in for a second. I thought I was losing my mind. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the protocol in the link. So before **linkurl.com** there should be something like **http://** or **https://** for a web-site, **ftp://** for an FTP-resource and etc.

Comment: only if the link is supposed to go to another site; if it's supposed to stay within the same site, the protocol portion is not needed